# How To Add Sum formula to cell in Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I am devloping a exe application using C# language.I would like to write a sum formula to a cell called Total, so that user may key in extra information in the excel generated by system and it is automatically reflected in the cellcalled total.

Below is the format of the excel file generated by system

Group1         ItemA      Qty1(generated in system)

```
                ItemB      Qty2(generated in system)

                ItemC        Qty3(key in by user)

               Total           Sum of (Qty1+Qty2+Qty3) .Formula=Sum(C1:C3)
```

Group2    until group n

I have try with the code

```
       objExcel.Cells[iRow, 3].Formula = "=SUM(C1:C3)";
```

but it is not working.It only sum the value from cell C1 to C3, but the formula is not written to the cells.

When user updating qty for itemC, it is not reflected in the total cell.

Does anyone has idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried locking the cells eg. SUM($C$1:$C$3), either than that I've also had little luck with excel programming.

Comment: This should be an comment!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below.

```
string formula = string.Format("=HYPERLINK(\"#{0}!{1}\", \"{2}\")", worksheet, cellRef, string.Format("Hyperlink number {0}", count));
```

More information can be found in the following link which I think could be a possible duplicate.

[Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400302/excel-worksheet-cellsrow-col-formula-vs-range-set-valuemissing-value-a)