# C# generate Excel with Formula shown as static text

Tags: c#, excel

I wrote a C# program trying to create an Excel sheet with formula like this

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

// the details of the class
Excel.Workbook obook;
Excel.Application oexcel = new Excel.Application();
oexcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;
obook = oexcel.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
Excel.Worksheet osheet;
osheet = (Excel.Worksheet)obook.Sheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

// create arrray to store formula
string[,] excelarray3 = new string[sample1.Width * sample1.Height, 1];

int rowct=0;
// some logic here to define the value of rowct (i.e. row count in excel)

// using for loop to assign formula into the array i.e.
for (int i =0; i <= rowct; i++){
 excelarry3[i,0]= "AND( A" + (i+1).ToString() + ">=AA1,A"+ (i+1).ToString() + "<=AB1,B"+ (i+1).ToString() + ">=AB1)";

}

// then assign value to excel
Excel.Range range3 = osheet.Range[osheet.Cells[2, 14], osheet.Cells[rowct + 1, 14]];
range3.Formula = excelarray3;
```

When I open the generated sheet, those formula assigned to the cells in column N are shown as text instead of the calculated result of the formula as in below picture
[image]

I didn't define the cell format at all. And I placed formula into column N, Q and T. The difference is that the formula in column Q, T are assigned to the cells one by one while the formula assigned to column N is pasting a string array to an excel range.

I am quite sure the formula is work as the formula start calculate after I select the cell then press Enter key

Comment: are using interop?

Comment: Hi Ka001, could you please let us know which library you are using? Also, what type is range1?

As a guess, I would suggest you need to set the formula, not the value of the cells but giving us the above information will help.

Comment: Yes, I am using interop. I also editted the post to show the details of my code for your information.   I tried to use Formula and seems the problem still here

Comment: It seems that the Excel formula can work if I assign it to the cells one by one but not work if assign into a range using array.  But I cannot assign it one by one as the data volume is large (30 worksheets x 7000 row each) which makes the program run very slow

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation of the [Range.Formula](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.formula?view=excel-pia) Member, i guess assigning values to this needs a string starting with "=".

> If the cell contains a formula, the Formula property returns the formula as a string in the same format that would be displayed in the formula bar (including the equal sign).

Try adding this when you build the formula string:

> ```cs
> // using for loop to assign formula into the array i.e.
> for (int i =0; i <= rowct; i++){
>   excelarry3[i,0]= "=AND( A" + (i+1).ToString() + ">=AA1 ; A"+ (i+1).ToString() + "<=AB1 ; B"+ (i+1).ToString() + ">=AB1)";
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks. But the problem still exist even I have added "=" in the code.

Comment: another thing i realized, the ```AND( bool1 ; bool2)``` syntax wants a semicolon (;) seperating the bool values and not a comma. but maybe that is just because of my localization

Comment: @ka001 Can you elaborate what exactly isn't working? So your cells still just display the Formula as a string, including the equal sign? Or are you getting Errors?

Comment: Maybe your cells have the "text" format? That should be the only time that a string starting with "=" is directly shown.

Comment: Hi Tanque, I added  a picture in the post to show the Excel worksheet generated for your information

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution here: [Excel.Worksheet.Cells[row,col] = "=Formula" vs. Range.set_Value(Missing.Value, arrayFormulas)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16819757/10396046)

In short, when applying a formula through the .formula property, the formula will display as static text if the applied range is multiple cells. This can be avoided by applying the formula (or array of formulas) in the .value property first and then assign the .value property on the .formula property.

Example:

```
myRange.value = "=my formula here"
myRange.formula = myRange.value
```